# Getting data from a watched variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a beginner question. Maybe I´m just too stupid.

Situation:
I have a interface where I can set alarm timer values via a slider. Everytime the value gets updated, it is written down to a file.
But when I set an interval I dont have access from the callback function to the watched variable, see timeCallback().

```
Vue.component('alarm-comp', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      data: {
        wakeup: {
          text: "Get up",
          time: 30, //timeout
        },
        ...
      },
      test: "test",
      ...
    },
  watch: {
    data: {
      handler(val) {
        this.saveSettings(); 
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.readSettings();
    setInterval(() => {this.timerCallback()}, (this.data.wakeup.time) * 1000); // -> time correctly set
  },
  methods: {
    timerCallback() {
      console.log(this.test); // -> test
      console.log(this.data.wakeup.time); // -> undefined
    },
  }
```

Comment: Use this.wakeup, not this.data.wakeup

Comment: @politinsa `wakeup` is nested in `this.data`...

Comment: What is undefined ? Data ? Wake-up ? Or time ?

Comment: Is there other code that might be modifying `data` before `timerCallback` is called? Perhaps in `readSettings`?

Comment: Probably an unrelated typo, but by my count you're missing a closing brace in your data declaration

Comment: data is undefined during timerCallback() but it`s rendered correctly and also being saved correctly when I change data.

Answer (score 0):

Hi mago and welcome to SO.

In VueJS information is sent down to components with props and sent up to the parent with emit event. If you want the parent component to know when the interval is done, you should emit that event up.

Check out this example: https://codepen.io/bergur/pen/jjwZxO?editors=1010

In my alarm component the main thing is

```
mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.$emit('finished', this.wakeup.text)
        }, (this.wakeup.time) * 1000
      );
  },
```

Here I create the finished event that sends the wakeup text (note that I removed the extra data wrapper)

In my parent object I listen to that event

```
<Alarm @finished="logMessage" />
```

And all that logMessage does is this:

```
methods: {
    logMessage(msg) {
      console.log('the alarm has finished and sent this message: ', msg)
    }
  },
```

Note that setInterval emits the event multiple times.

Comment: Thank you. But that is not the problem. I want to push an IPC message to my electron framework to open up a new window - This works. But the content (data) is not transmitted - as (data) is stated as undefined in the timerCallback()

Comment: I think that solution would work, maybe I'm misunderstanding you. When setInterval callback finishes it fires an event. You can send whatever data you want with the event. When listen to that event in your electron framework then you can do whatever you want there, like opening up a window.

Comment: The problem is that in the scope of the setInterval callback my data object is stated as "undefined" and I cant understand why. So even emitting the signal with undefined data will result in a window with undefined data and not my desired message.

Answer (score 0):

i'm trying to figure it out since yesterday, for some reason, your code is not executing the mounted hook, i just duplicate your code (is missing a close bracket before watch, maybe just for the example code) and realise that if you change the mounted for other hook like created, this i'll trigger and i'll work, at least in my example.

`created() {
    this.readSettings();
    setInterval(() => {this.timerCallback()}, (this.data.wakeup.time) * 1000);
}`

Do you really need the mounted hook, or can you change to created?